# Read Pdf with C

Tags: c, linux, pdf, libharu

I want to be able to read the content of pdf files. I need to do that with C on Linux.

The closer i can get to this was [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730/open-source-pdf-library-for-cc-application) but I think Haru can only create pdf and is not able to read them (not 100% sure).

PS: I only need the plain text from pdf

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Check out [libpoppler](http://poppler.freedesktop.org/).  I've never used it work extracting text, just querying PDF attributes.  It's pretty easy to use.

Comment: I think libpoppler is too "big" for what i want. It uses QT and other stuff that i think it is unnecessary.

Comment: Poppler has optional frontends for glib and Qt (to fit nicely into their object systems), but is not required.

Comment: Ok! I saw that it is already on Ubuntu repositories. I will take a look.

Answer (score 2):

How well do you need to parse them?
Just extracting strings should be relatively easy, fully accurate rendering is harder.
Take a look at the source for evince or ghostscript?

This is for C++ but might be a good starting point for understanding PDF structure http://www.codeproject.com/KB/cpp/ExtractPDFText.aspx (sorry wrong link before)

Comment: I only need the plain text from pdf files.

Answer (score 0):

Another possible, though I've never used it is VersyPDF.  It claims to allow you to edit PDFs ... http://versypdf.sybrex-systems-ltd.qarchive.org/