# How can I create a PDF file programmatically with C?

Tags: c, pdf

I want to write some String data to a pdf file programmatically, i want to know what are the C libraries that i have to use and how to use them

Answer (score 9):

There's [libHaru](http://libharu.org/wiki/Main_Page) and [PDFlib](http://www.pdflib.com/download/pdflib-family/pdflib-6/).

Comment: Oops, didn't see that the Haru library was already suggested!

Comment: Good that you provided the link. Other people also seem to like libHaru.

Comment: The current URL for libHaru is now http://libharu.org/

Answer (score 7):

The Haru library, on sourceforge.  We have had good experience with it.

Answer (score 1):

[PoDoFo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/) is a good option. [Here is a discussion listing](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730/open-source-pdf-library-for-c-c-application) libraries for C/C++ languages.

Comment: Unfortunately, PoDoFo is C++.  The question was for a C library

Answer (score 1):

Yes, you can use C++ or C or any text processing language to create PDF files.  The preferred method is to go to [Adobe PDF Website](http://www.adobe.com/training/books/acrobat.html) and get a book or the specification for the latest version of PDF.  They own the language, so they are the official starting place.

Comment: They do not own the PDF specification, it is an ISO standard, and anyone and everyone is allowed to use it.