# free C/C++ PDF creator library Linux (not libharu)

Tags: c++, c, pdf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Open source PDF library for C/C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730/open-source-pdf-library-for-c-c-application)

C/C++ PDF library Linux (not libharu). I need some reference to such libraries. For now use libharu but have some problems there.

edited:
my problem is impossibility to know height of text rendered as paragraph in Rect or at least render multilined text by using \n special character.

Comment: What are the problems you are facing with `libharu`?

Comment: i dont know if `mupdf` could be what you want?

Comment: @smerlin isnt `mupdf` only viewer?

Answer (score 1):

You could try with [PoDoFo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/about.html).

> The PoDoFo library is a free, portable C++ library which includes
>   classes to parse PDF files and modify their contents into memory

Comment: for now +1, and i will scrutinize it well and then accept. thanks.