# how to save bytes to pdf file (how to change each pdf page to bytes)

Tags: c++, c, pdf

I have a pdf or word file, and read it in bytes, so I can encrypted it, now, I want to know how can I write these bytes to pdf file, so user see it as Garbage codes unless the file was decrypted?

Is there a method to change each page to bytes? I need c or c++ code. Because I want to encrypt each pdf page, and I can encrypt bytes data, also I want to know when I encrypt each page, is it still a pdf file, and just each page is Garbage characters(unreadable codes, messy code).

Comment: why don't you just encrypt the entire .pdf file?

Comment: when I read it, I just need show few pages which i will decrypt, if encrypt entire file, i need decrypt entire file

Answer (score 1):

The [PDF specification](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/pdf_reference.html) already describes PDF encryption: encrypted PDF objects are removed from the top level and instead contained within an object stream (another object, with `/Type /ObjStm`) encrypted with `/Filter /Crypt`.

Answer (score 0):

It already is bytes - it is how you interpret the bytes that matter!

With a bit of knowledge about PDF format you could write something to encrypt a file such that it was still PDF but appears as unreadable garbage*, but if you just encrypt the PDF file (or bytes in it), then it won't still be a PDF file.

* This is just an assumption - I haven't actually done it myself.

Comment: It is a great solution, yeah, I am just finding a open source lib for write pdf file, just as you said, write encrypted bytes as a pdf file,  dou you know any libs?

Comment: Sorry, I've not written PDFs programatically.

Answer (score -1):

[This](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730/open-source-pdf-library-for-c-c-application) post provides useful libraries to create pdf. Before writing the pdf to file you should be able to encrypt the text.