# C++ library for creating pdfs with many languages supported?

Tags: c++, pdf-generation, hindi

My dilemma is this: We have been using libharu for the creation of our pdfs but we recently added Hindi to our software and from what I can find, libharu doesn't support it.

I have looked around and have been unable to find a library similar to libharu (doesn't need to be open source) that supports all the languages we use, but I have failed.

I checked out all the libraries mentioned in this post, but none of them met my needs:

[Open source PDF library for C/C++ application?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58730/open-source-pdf-library-for-c-c-application)

Also, that post is a few years old. >_<

So I ask you, kind stackoverflow people, do you know of a library for creating and editing pdfs (in c++) that supports at least the following languages? (English, Spanish, French, Turkish, German, Russian, Japanese, Chinese, Arabic, and Hindi)

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried going to the source?
[Adobe PDF Developer SDK](http://www.adobe.com/devnet/pdf/library.html)

Adobe Systems <s>owns</s> invented the PDF language.  I recommend talking to them first before going open source.  They may have some libraries or SDKs to use with PDFs.

Comment: Isn't PDF an open ISO standard for some years now?

Comment: According to Wikipedia, there is an ISO PDF standard.  I didn't think Adobe would relinquish control, but it did.

Answer (score 1):

I have used [JagPDF](http://www.jagpdf.org/) few times and from my last experience I think embedding fonts in the pdf might solve your problem.