# Creating PDF from PS programmatically on embedded platform

Tags: c++, pdf, embedded, postscript

**Is there a library/tool that can be used in C/C++ that would convert the PS (post script) file to .PDF file, on embedded platform (proprietary operating system, no windows, no linux)?**

I was looking for some kind of library that could be ported to our OS. I have found basically only Ghostscript, but issue there is with the license, if i understood it correctly, we would have to make our source public, which is not possible for us...

Maybe a little bit more background, we are trying to find format that will be easily viewable by user. We already have our output in PS for other reasons (printer). But now we want to provide this output in file by itself, so we are trying to find feasible file format. We are considering the PS itself, but usual user does not have PS viewer, so that's why I am trying to find something to convert this to PDF. **So perhaps alternative question could be, is there some another format that can be easily acquired from PS, such that "regular" user can view it?**

Comment: HTML seems like the obvious solution, or perhaps SVG?

Comment: Do you really need to do this on the embedded device? Could the file be converted offline to pdf and use that readily converted file in the device?

Comment: @barny Hm HTML would be suitable i think, but is there such library?

Comment: @teroi Unfortunately it has be on embedded, otherwise this would be an issue...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main complexity for converting PostScript to something else comes from the fact, that PostScript is a programming language and PostScrip files in fact are programs executed on the printer.

In contrast to PostScript, PDF is not a programming language. When converting PostScript to PDF (or anything else), you actually have to run the PostScript program and record the graphic primitive calls, executed during the execution of the PostScript program.

This general approach is needed, when you want to convert PostScript programs from any source to PDF.

But you wrote, that you are creating the PostScript code yourself. Perhaps your PostScript program is just a linear sequence of calls to drawing primitives and does not use anything like subroutines or control structures.

If not, it might be easy to change your generator to do those computation at creation time,that currently are performed at print time. You would end up in a linear sequence of calls to drawing primitives.

When there are no more computations done at print-time, it should not be too hard to directly create PDF instead of PostScript. This [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/58737/6832488) mentions an open source PDF generation library, that uses an MIT style license.

Comment: Interesting, and you are right, we are using limited set of postscript commands, nothing complicated i think, will have to check. But your idea should work I think. I was probably looking for unnecessarily complex solution...

Answer (score 0):

The AGPL licence for Ghostscript would require you to make your source open, yes. However Ghostscript is dual licenced, in addition to the AGPL licence you can purchase a commercial licence, which doesn't require you to open source your own code.

Rather than converting to PDF you can, of course, also simply use Ghostscript to render the PostScript to a bitmap, its usually pretty easy to wrap a viewer around that.

I should point out that there are other companies offering commercial licences for PostScript interpreters which are capable of creating PDF files and/or rendering PostScript. Adobe is the obvious one, there's also Global Graphics.

These days there are not many players left in the field, if you want to handle PostScript, and the AGPL or similar licences won't suit you, then you will need to go commercial.

Comment: I was kinda worried that this would be the case, since my managers will probably rather switch to another format than go with commercial license. But anyway good to know, thanks for answer.