# outputting pdf files using C++ file I/O

Tags: c++, file

I was trying to output a string to a file using File I/O of C++, but I decided to change the extension of the output file to .pdf, .docx and so on.

None of them seem to open up.

So are there any more internal translations required in order to make that file a proper(file which opens) pdf or docx??

```
void convert(char *file){

    ifstream in(file);
    ofstream out("out.pdf",ios::out);

    char str;

    while(in && out){
        in.get(str);
        out.put(str);
    }

    in.close();
    out.close();
    cout<<"Done!!!";
}
```

Comment: File extensions mean nothing, they are at best a hint to the OS as to which application it should open when you double click on a file in the file explorer.

Comment: so, is it just a .txt file which would open up normally?

Comment: The file formats you mentioned are not equal. Each one has its own format specification. A valid PDF file (one that works when you open it) has to follow the PDF format specification, otherwise editor/reader applications won't be able to parse it. A txt file, on the other hand, is pure text, so editors/readers don't need any extra effort to show its contents (except when dealing with encoding, BOM, etc).

Comment: You need to read the detailed specification of the format of PDF files, then write code to produce a file in that format. There might be a library to help with this.

Comment: ***So are there any more internal translations required in order to make that file a proper(file which opens) pdf or docx??*** Yes and for pdf it will be months to years of work for you to implement this if you succeed.

Comment: ***so, is it just a .txt file which would open up normally?*** pdf is much more complex than that.

Comment: a plain .txt file doesn't need any translations??

Comment: ***a plain .txt file doesn't need any translations??*** It does not.

Comment: thanks @drescherjm

Comment: Next time, give more motivation in your question. I tried to guess (apparently with success, since you accepted my answer), but when asking something here you should give some context & motivation.

Comment: sure @BasileStarynkevitch

Answer (score 3, accepted):

[PDF](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Portable_Document_Format) is (and also `docx` which actually is [OOXML](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Office_Open_XML); and of course also [OpenDocument](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenDocument) & [DocBook](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DocBook)) a [file format](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/File_format) (and quite a complex one), specified in a complex English document (the ISO 32000 standard) defining which sequences of bytes are valid (and what they represent).

Grossly speaking a PDF file contains elementary steps to draw ink on paper or pixels on screen. With gross simplification, these steps include things like "move the pen to position x=23 y=50", "choose the *Arial* font of 10pt", "draw the word `abc` in that font at that position", "choose the pink color for the pen" etc etc, but the details are much more complex.

File extensions don't mean anything (except as an important convention).

To generate a PDF file, you either need to spend weeks or months to study the specification of that PDF format, or to use some library for that (see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/q/58730/841108) question, and also [podofo](http://podofo.sourceforge.net/), [poppler](https://poppler.freedesktop.org/) and several other libraries). Even with the help of a library, you need to understand something about that format.

> Are there any more internal translations required in order to make that file

I'm not sure to understand what you mean by translation (a better word would be "converter"). You could generate PDF by sending some *other* content to a suitable program emitting PDF. You might consider using some [document formatter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Typesetting) (like [LaTeX](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/LaTeX) thru `pdflatex`, or [Lout](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lout_(software)), or some older variant of [troff](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Troff), etc..) which you would feed with a higher-level file format containing text formatting directives mixed with (some encoding of) the text to be formatted. On Unix like systems you might even use some command [pipeline](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pipeline_(Unix)) (to avoid writing some "temporary" file), perhaps using [popen(3)](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/popen.3.html) and related functions.

Answer (score 0):

To write a pdf, docx, etc. you need to setup a file header, and format the data correctly. Changing the extension does not really do much if anything at all.

You will have to use an outside an outside library or format the code yourself. Below are a couple of examples of extensions you can use:

[PDF](https://github.com/galkahana/PDF-Writer)
[docx](http://docxfactory.com/)